# Django response 403 for csrf_token rejected when jquery ajax post a formdata with proccessData=false

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

```
formdata = new FormData($form);
case ("filesystem"):
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:$form.attr('action'),
                xhr: xhr_provider,
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType:false
            })
            .fail(function(Response){alert(Response.responseText)})
            .done(function(response){
                alert("111");
                if (response.has_errors){
                    render_errors($form, response);
               } else {
                $form.closest(".modal").modal("hide");
               }
              });
            alert("12345");
            break;
```

when I try to send the `formdata` contains a file to Django , I will face two Problems:
If I set`processData: false`and  `contentType:false`as all the others suggested, Django will reject this POST with a 403 error.

If I comment out these two lines which set `processData` and `contentType` to be `false`, Jquery will throw a `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` ,which is another common question ,the solution is set`processData: false`and  `contentType:false`. Meanwhile ,the formdata which contains a file has successfully send to Django and handled without error.

So I was confused, What  should I do to send a formdata with file to Django

Answer (score 0):

In your `views.py` you should put this decorator to the function to process post to prevent 403:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def your_function(request):
    # your logic
```